# Grabbing a custom product image label in Magento?

Tags: php, image, magento, label

I have a block on my front page that is grabbing the two newest products with a custom product image called `image_feature_front_right`.

I use this code as the query:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter("image_feature_front_right", array("notnull" => 1));
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter("image_feature_front_right", array("neq" => 'no_selection'));
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('updated_at', 'DESC');
$_productCollection->setPageSize(2);
```

I am able to get:

- the image: `echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image_feature_front_right')->directResize(230,315,4)`
- the product url: `echo $_product->getProductUrl()`
- the product name: `$this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true)`

The only thing I am unable to get is the custom images label. I have tried `echo $this->getImageLabel($_product, 'image_feature_front_right')`, but that seems to do nothing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Tre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine this is some sort of magento bug. The issue seems to be that the Magento core is not setting the custom_image_label attribute. Whereas for the default built-in images [image, small_image, thumbnail_image] it does set these attributes - so you could do something like:

```
$_product->getData('small_image_label');
```

If you look at `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getImageLabel()` it just appends '_label' to the `$mediaAttributeCode` that you pass in as the 2nd param and calls `$_product->getData()`.

If you call `$_product->getData('media_gallery');`  you'll see the custom image label is available. It's just nested in an array. So use this function:

```
function getImageLabel($_product, $key) {
    $gallery = $_product->getData('media_gallery');
    $file = $_product->getData($key);
    if ($file && $gallery && array_key_exists('images', $gallery)) {    
        foreach ($gallery['images'] as $image) {
            if ($image['file'] == $file)
                return $image['label'];
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

It'd be prudent to extend the Magento core code (Ideally `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`, but I don't think Magento lets you override Abstract classes), but if you need a quick hack - just stick this function in your phtml file then call:

```
<?php echo getImageLabel($_product, 'image_feature_front_right')?>
```